# how to change my IP address to another country?

Tags: ip, proxy, ip-address, tcpip

I need to access that [website](https://www.syria-visa.sy/passport/) which is allowed to be accessed from Syria.
I have tried to change my IP address to make my device as Syrian device. however my attempt went wrong.

here are my steps:

1. I get IP address from [here](https://lite.ip2location.com/syrian-arab-republic-ip-address-ranges).
2. Then, I did all [steps to change IP manually](https://winbuzzer.com/2021/07/28/how-change-ip-address-windows-10-xcxwbt/).
3. Finally, I opened the [targeted website](https://www.syria-visa.sy/passport/) which needs Syrian IP.

the result
my internet disconnect !!!

did I miss some steps or need to do something further ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You cannot just assign yourself a random IP Address. You need to use a proxy or VPN to accomplish what your attempting to do.  We will be unable to make any recommendations on any services that might be applicable to your desire to appear to be in another country

Comment: @Community I need to open that [website](https://www.syria-visa.sy/passport/) and tried to do so by changing my IP. however, my ultimate goal is to access that [website](https://www.syria-visa.sy/passport/) whither using IP - proxy - etc. I don't know the way I don't know how. this is my question.

Comment: @Ramhound since I can't do this by myself and I should do this using proxy or VPN. is there any free proxy solution?

Comment: There probably is a ton. The duplicate explains how to accomplish your goal. It doesn’t tell you what service provider to select